# How to stylize input field as on twitter?

Tags: css, input, opacity

I want to stylize input field as on twitter for authorization. I have the following HTML markup:

```
<input hint="hint" name="name" type="text">
```

I need to changed an opacity of the text that contains in the attribute `hint` on focus. How can I do it?

Comment: Use placeholder="your hint" but supported on modern browses only

Comment: @SVS - There are numerous [polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) that will allow the `placeholder` attribute to work in older browsers too, but I think the OP is looking for something a bit more than a native placeholder.

Comment: I need to use `hint`. If I use `placeholder`, it will be hidden on focus...

Comment: Use value as hint & remove it on keyup function using jquery & style it as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/NLrRC/16/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <input type="text" />
 <span>Username or email</span>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.container{position:relative; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;}
.container input{position:relative; z-index:98;}
.container span{position: absolute; z-index:99; color:#ccc; left:5px; top:3px; font-size:11px;}
```

**Jquery**(Updated: Removed bug of clear input on focusout)

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $(this).next().css('z-index', '0');
});
$('input').blur(function(){
  if($('input').val()=== ''){
    $('input').next().css('z-index', '99');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey! use this updated answer it will not clear input on focusout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    input[hint="hint"]:focus{
        opacity: .4;
    }
```